# Is it possible to divide an Android application into two APK files?

Tags: android, resources, apk

I have android application (single apk file) with code and ga lot of graphics, It takes a lot of space. I want to devide my huge application into two parts. The first is a source code and minor graphice (takes low space), the second part includes all other graphic. When user launches first application, it uses graphic from another application.

1) Is solution it possible?

2) If it is possible, how can I access from first apk to a resource file at SD card, whick stores in another zip/archive/jar/or apk?

Comment: most people wouldn't want to download an app that big. Try downloading the images from a server and cacheing them (maybe in a database) at the start of your app.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can provide your graphic as a Content Provider in one application and then read them  in another application.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Library Projects](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/projects/index.html) to achieve this.

Comment: A library project is still packaged into the same final .apk, not solving the size issue.

Comment: Thank You! Is it possible to include Android Library project in a runtime?

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of ways to do this. One of the more popular is to require the application to download the large graphics on "first-run". This is done by most large game apps.

Comment: Thank you! How do I can implement this additional graphic pack? Is it a Android Library project, ore it can be a jar-file, ore it can be a simple png/jper files on SD-card?

Comment: I would suggest you download the files to either the internal storage or the SD card. You can read about how to do this here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html